# Show ADO recordset in subform

Tags: ms-access, adodb, recordset

I have inspected a lot of websites and books, and I still cannot solve my problem.

I want to show a Recordset in a form's subform as a table. The Recordset results from a query (query is valid, and the recordset is generated properly - checked with `Debug.Print`). I know that I have to use the following line in VBA code: `Set Me.subform.Form.Recordset = rs` but it only works when the Sourceobject is manually set in the Properties window (e.g., a table). When it is set, I noticed that the subform property `.Form`. Otherwise, there is information that refers to an object which is closed or does not exist. So I was looking for a dynamically creating this property, but I didn't find anything working.

Moreover, I want to apply some changes to this Recordset before show it, but first of all, I want to show it raw.

Comment: Review [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49551221/7296893), while the question is substantially different it probably solves your problem.

Comment: You can use SQL statement as subform record source where you can apply filter with multiple criteria, sort etc.

Comment: @ErikA, thank you for that - I will consider it.

Comment: @Harun24HR, I want to group the result concatenating strings on duplicates. I have read some posts about it, and I think the quickest way is to do this on the recordset.

Comment: I have created a new table, which I truncate and then insert generated data on every change. Then there is no problem with showing it in a subform. I think this is the best solution for this.